# Null value of mean in dataframe columns after imputation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, null, mean, imputation

I have a dataframe where I imputed nulls with the mean of group ID. The null count after applying imputation for all such columns is 0. When I do a describe, the mean of few columns which were imputed shows as NaN. The null count for such columns is 0 and the data type is 'float16' (changed it from 'float64' to save on in-memory computations). How could this possibly happen?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pelase consider adding the content of your dataframe as code and not as an image. Can you provide the output of `data['feature_1']`?

Comment: Agreed that seeing more data would be helpful, though it claims a count of > 1e6 rows, so maybe not all of it. The std is also showing zero in almost all the other features.  Maybe something in the imputation step is strange... can you show more code around how you manipulated this df?  Separately, can you test it on a subset of the records (like `.head(n)`) to see if it ever works, and maybe be able to narrow down where the issue is?